# Add string to a string from users input Swift ( not to an array!)

Tags: swift, string

I have a homework in which i have to take users input from TextField, check if it's not nil and then show it inside Label. When user types in new text, it should be showed in the same label, next to the old text( separated by space). I can not use array.
I tried to do += thing but it only shows the latest input, without previous one.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var textTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func type(_ sender: Any) {
    var text:String = ""
    var newText:String = ""
    if textTextField.text != nil {
        newText  = textTextField.text!
        text += newText
        textLabel.text =  "\(text)"
        textTextField.text = nil
    }
```

Where am I making a mistake?
at the end it should look like this
[screen interface example from my professor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaJ9j.png)

Comment: Are you sure you want the `textTextField.text = nil`? Is it meant to clear the text?

Comment: Just move the declaration of `text` outside of the function so it becomes a class property. Then it will retain the new values between calls to the function

Comment: Setting the `text` property of an `UITextField` to `nil` is bad practice. According to the docs it's never `nil` – unlike `UILabel`. The default value is an empty string

Comment: @vadian Yes. I was about to comment that as well. Just would be worth mentioning that the same is not true for a UILabel [text](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620538-text) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly there, you don't need `text` or `newText`.

I also used an `if let ...` binding so you don't need to force-unwrap after already checking if it is `nil`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func type(_ sender: Any) {
    if let current = textTextField.text {
        textLabel.text += current
        textTextField.text = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! adding  += really made things work!

Comment: @KseniiaPiskun `textLabel.text?.append(current)` should work as well. Make sure to initialize your label with some text or an empty string.

Comment: @KseniiaPiskun I still find the `textTextField.text = nil` a bit unusual, why do you do that?

Comment: bc otherwise users input stays in text field( on iphone/simulator screen) and you need to delete it before you type in new input. with textTextField.text = nil I make sure that textfield is empty after user presses the button. Maybe there is a better way to do it, but I came up with this)

Comment: @KseniiaPiskun Setting to an empty string (`""`) is probably better. As others said, it is advised you don't set it to `nil` yourself.